# View the keyboard's list of learned words? (user dictionary)

Tags: keyboard, dictionary, auto-correct

Is there a way to view a list of all the words the keyboard has learned from my input? My dictionary saves things like passwords and they pop up as auto-suggestions (!!!!!) which is a monstrously horrible security risk. But I can't possibly remember every piece of private information I have ever typed into the keyboard so I need to see the list of learned words and delete everything that shouldn't be there.

This on a Samsung J5.

Comment: If your keyboard app uses Android's built-in dictionary, then see under **Languages & Input** ➔ **Personal Dictionary** in Settings. Or with root access: `sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.userdictionary/databases/user_dict.db 'SELECT * FROM words'`. If the keyboard app builds its own dictionary, you need to look in its private directory, or may be in app settings.

Comment: Fix question - learned words are not user dictionary